# Constraint Violation when persisting One To Many relation

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

In a spring mvc application using hibernate and MySQL, I am getting the following constraint violation exception:

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:  
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails  
(`mybd`.`hl7_documententity`, CONSTRAINT `hl7_documententity_ibfk_1`   
FOREIGN KEY (`ptcode`, `ptcodesystem`)    
REFERENCES `hl7_generalcode` (`code`, `codesystem`))
```

The problem occurs when I try to save a `DocumentEntity` containing a property of type `GeneralCode`, both of which are defined below.

I have read many postings and blogs on this error, but none seem to resolve my problem.  **How can I resolve this error?**

Here is the `DocumentEntity` class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "hl7_documententity")
public class HL7DocumentEntity extends BaseEntity{

    //other properties

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({ @JoinColumn(name = "ptcode", referencedColumnName = "code"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "ptcodesystem", referencedColumnName = "codesystem")
    })
    private HL7GeneralCode providertype;

    //getters and setters    
}
```

Here is the `GeneralCode` class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "hl7_generalcodes")
public class HL7GeneralCode implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8620565054475096516L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private HL7EmbedCodePK codePk;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "providertype")
    private Set<HL7DocumentEntity> documententities;

    ////////////getters and setters    
}
```

Here is the code from the controller:

```
HL7GeneralCode authcode = processGeneralCode(grandkid);
HL7GeneralCode testcode = this.clinicService.findGeneralCodeByPK(authcode.getCodePk().getCode(), authcode.getCodePk().getCodesystem());
if(testcode==null){
    authcode.addDocumententity(mydent);
    this.clinicService.savehl7GeneralCode(authcode);
    mydent.setProvidertype(authcode);
    //this next line throws the error
    this.clinicService.savehl7DocumentEntity(mydent);
}else{
    //other stuff
}
```

Here is the dao method:

```
@Repository
public class JpaSomethingRepositoryImpl implements SomethingRepository {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void savehl7DocumentEntity(HL7DocumentEntity de) {
        HL7GeneralCode code = de.getProvidertype();
        if(code !=null && code.getCodePk()==null){//HL7GeneralCode is not persistent. We don't support that
            throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot persist an adress using a non persistent HL7GeneralCode");
        }
        System.out.println("=========================== inside jpaCdaRespository.saveDocEntity(de)");
        de.setProvidertype(null);
        if(code.getDocumententities()!=null){
            ArrayList<HL7DocumentEntity> addrList = new ArrayList<HL7DocumentEntity>();
            addrList.addAll(code.getDocumententities());
            addrList.remove(de);
            Set<HL7DocumentEntity> myaddrs = new HashSet<HL7DocumentEntity>(addrList);
            code.setDocumententities(myaddrs);
        }
        code = em.merge(code); 
        de.setProvidertype(code);
        code.addDocumententity(de);

        if (de.getId() == null) {
            System.out.println("[[[[[[[[[[[[ about to persist de ]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]");
            em.persist(de);
        } else {
            System.out.println("]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]] about to merge de [[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[");
            de = em.merge(de);
        }
    }
}
```

The executed SQL statement and the actual values that hibernate is trying to insert via the sql are:

```
[[[[[[[[[[[[ about to persist de ]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]
DEBUG SQL - insert into hl7_documententity (author_id, authpar_id, entitytype, id_extension, id_root, ptcode, ptcodesystem, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into hl7_documententity (author_id, authpar_id, entitytype, id_extension, id_root, ptcode, ptcodesystem, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
TRACE BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - <null>
TRACE BasicBinder - binding parameter [2] as [INTEGER] - <null>
TRACE BasicBinder - binding parameter [3] as [VARCHAR] - <null>
TRACE BasicBinder - binding parameter [4] as [VARCHAR] - NI
TRACE BasicBinder - binding parameter [5] as [VARCHAR] - nullFlavor
TRACE BasicBinder - binding parameter [6] as [VARCHAR] - UNK
TRACE BasicBinder - binding parameter [7] as [VARCHAR] - HL7NullFlavor
TRACE BasicBinder - binding parameter [8] as [INTEGER] - 32787
WARN  SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 1452, SQLState: 23000
ERROR SqlExceptionHelper - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`docbd`.`hl7_documententity`, CONSTRAINT `hl7_documententity_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`ptcode`, `ptcodesystem`) REFERENCES `hl7_generalcode` (`code`, `codesystem`))
INFO  AbstractBatchImpl - HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
WARN  warn - Handler execution resulted in exception
```

You can read the EmbedCodePK class code [by clicking on this link](https://jumpshare.com/v/3fichxmdYCTUUVSuEgVx?b=wuwfuMkWZbyF7NVY2iAi).
You can read the entire stack trace [by clicking on this link](https://jumpshare.com/v/8IdY5SnPXFIYyE4uI7EA?b=oucVpeyqPuoliRhogmmK).
[Here is a link](https://jumpshare.com/b/mKTlldJRrL0qhKEG88nT) to the code for the BaseEntity class.

Comment: I've seen that error, but when trying to delete/update. Let me explain... If I have a class called `Person` and a one to many relationship to `Job` and there exists a database entry for a `Person` and it references a `Job`, if I try to delete that `Person` before deleting all of its `Job`s I will produce that error. I don't have time to look at your code but I assume its the opposite, you are updating a parent element when a child references that parent. Oh I just looked at your code and see no primary key? You should create one with `@Id`

Comment: Well I see your `@EmbeddedId` and I think it's something to do with that, if you are changing that when a reference is set to its old value then that error will happen

Comment: I couldn't find any explanation. You need to debug the Hibernate code.

Comment: i think you should put another breakpoint before your em.persist(de) and look at your de object since it violates your db constraints.

Comment: If you have a constraint violation when persisting one to many relation, can't you just persist one fewer?

Comment: @CodeMed: just some failed wordplay.  (I first read your question as "one too many" rather than "one-to-many.")

Comment: I guess calling em.flush() method after **code = em.merge(code);** may solve your problem. You seem to be executing two operations *(em.merge(code) and em.persist(de))* in the same transaction. Hibernate is not required to execute the database operations until the transaction is committed.

Comment: I believe this has something to do with @Transactional annotation. Have you tried using programmatic transaction management? Also do you have both service and dao layer? And how do you get entity manager in savehl7DocumentEntity() method

Comment: @Transactional annotation is generally used in service layer. I guess you need to move most of your code to service layer and keep only database specific operations in dao layer. Not sure if this works. I would give a try.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60121/discussion-between-naresh-vavilala-and-codemed).

Comment: I think there is a problem with your anotations for ManytoOne and OnetoMany. Did you used these annotations in an other place and it worked?

Comment: I will post the answer tomorow since now I am on the phone. But from what i see it is an confusion for jpa becase in many to one you create a new table basicaly where you tell jpa it should manage the keys. But in the onetomany you don't use the same table for reference. Hope it makes sense what I am trying to say.

Comment: @CodeMed It is annoying that you seem to keep on deleting your comments. How is someone who stumbles upon this years later supposed to follow the conversation when you delete half of it???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "providertype")
private Set<HL7DocumentEntity> documententities;
```

To this:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "Link_Documents", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "codePk", unique = true)}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "change_this_with_primary_key_variable_name_from_HL7DocumentEntity")})
 private Set<HL7DocumentEntity> documententities;
```

And in HL7DocumentEntity change as follows:

This

```
@ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({ @JoinColumn(name = "ptcode", referencedColumnName = "code"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "ptcodesystem", referencedColumnName = "codesystem")
    })
    private HL7GeneralCode providertype;
```

Change to this:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinTable(name = "Link_Documents", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "change_this_with_primary_key_variable_name_from_HL7DocumentEntity")}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "codePk")})
  private HL7GeneralCode providertype;
```

I think you have to change "change_this_with_primary_key_variable_name_from_HL7DocumentEntity" with "id" like it is in BaseEntity but take a look at your sql table, you willsee there the correct name.

I hope you notice How I told JPA to use the same "Link_Documents" table for linking the 2 tables. I think this is were your mistake is. Just make sure to change where I told you with the correct variable  name and I think it should work

Comment: No. I will try to explain now my code. If you want we can talk in chat

Comment: I will be onLINE for at least 10 hours. Mayby even more. This is a temporary email I have set, contact me here when you can talk 5c0821f4@opayq.com .I will respond wethen 5 minutes after you send it.

Comment: I hope you understand how a many to many and a one to one relationship works in SQL. If not here is a tutorial for ManyToMany: http://en.tekstenuitleg.net/articles/software/database-design-tutorial/many-to-many.html and here it is for OneToOne http://en.tekstenuitleg.net/articles/software/database-design-tutorial/one-to-one.html If you understand this 2 then it will be more simple to understant the OneToMany relation.

Answer (score -4):

you know i would start by cleaning up this code.

Though the hibernate documentation might tell you placing those annotations on the field variables is ok,,, its a bad idea as a standard. field level requires hibernate to create a proxy before the field can be access in the case of lazy fetches. so just get use to doing it correctly and you wont have the misfortune of finding issues. move all those annotations to the getters as property level access doesnt require the proxy.

field level variables should be private.

you are casting an Integer to an Integer in there... some of that stuff makes me not want to look at it and truthfully will probably be a silly bit of laziness that ends up being your problem.

while you are at it go ahead an initialize the set with new HashSet(0); Things like that. Still broken update us.